# Entity Framework AddRange: how to map to stored procedure?

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am working with EF and stored procedures for data modification operations. So far I have been able to map stored procedures to basic operations such as Insert, Update, and Delete for one row (entity).

However, I would like to map also `AddRange`. I need a dedicate stored procedure for this operation and it does not work for me that EF calls my add stored procedure n times. I would like that it calls my `AddRange` stored procedures once.

I would also like to map another common tasks as `Clear` but for now `AddRange` is my top priority. Is this kind of mapping possible in EF? If not, is this something that would make sense to add or I am looking into the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about `AddRange` which is an extension method of `DbSet`.

You can't map a store procedure to `AddRange` or `Clear`, because these methods are just preparing the entities and nothing will be added to database until `SaveChanges` is called.

If you need to Add multiple records with one db call, you can call it like this and not with `DbSet`

```
public class Context : DbContext
{

    public void AddList()
    {
        this.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityType>("storedProcedureName",params);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I can map a store procedure to e.g. Add. My store procedure gets called when I call SaveChanges. Actually that is what I am doing right now. I do not see a reason why it has to be different for AddRange or Clear.

Comment: because when you map a store procedure to Add, it won't me mapped to Add method of DbSet, as you said your store procedure will be called after SaveChanges. your store procedure will be mapped for Add **a record** whether it's coming from Add or AddRange. feel free to ask if it's not clear enough?